# Install php trader on mac os

Tags: mac, php, pecl

I am trying to install on my MAC the trader modul from PHP. I am running on PHP 7.1

Here my error:

```
sudo pecl install trader

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Downloader.php on line 592

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/php5-7.1.1-20170213-100732/lib/php/PEAR/Downloader.php on line 592
downloading trader-0.5.0.tgz ...
Starting to download trader-0.5.0.tgz (299,829 bytes)
.........................................................done: 299,829 bytes

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Validator.php on line 870

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/php5-7.1.1-20170213-100732/lib/php/PEAR/PackageFile/v2/Validator.php on line 870
332 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `autoconf` is not installed on your system.

The easiest way to get that is to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), then run:

```
brew install autoconf
```

Generally, I would recommend installing third-party dependencies through Homebrew, since you won't need to run `sudo` to do anything with these packages. See [this guide](https://medium.com/@romaninsh/install-php-7-2-on-macos-high-sierra-with-homebrew-bdc4d1b04ea6) for some more info.